# My Room database refuses to create itself and execute functions

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-room

```
class CarManagerFragment : Fragment() {
    //initialize the needed variables
    private lateinit var db : Database
    private lateinit var carDao: CarDao
    private lateinit var etPlate: EditText
    ...
    private lateinit var btnCarAdd: Button
    private lateinit var rvCars: RecyclerView

    //creates the view with the onclicklistener
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_car_manager, container, false)

        //initialize the variables
        db = Database.getDatabase(requireContext())
        carDao = db.carDao()
        etPlate = view.findViewById(R.id.etPlate)
        ...
        etOwner = view.findViewById(R.id.etOwner_id)
        btnCarAdd = view.findViewById(R.id.btnAdd_car)
        rvCars = view.findViewById(R.id.rvCars)

        //show all the cars in the listview
        rvCars.adapter = CarAdapter(carDao.getAll())
        
        btnCarAdd.setOnClickListener {

            //create a new car
            val car = Car(
                plate = etPlate.text.toString(),
                ...
                year = etYear.text.toString().toInt(),
                owner = etOwner.text.toString()
            )

            //insert the car in the database
            carDao.insert(car)

        }
        return view
    }
}
```

My data access object classes(a customer can have many cards and a car can have many interventions):

```
@Dao
interface CarDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM car")
    fun getAll(): List<Car>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM car WHERE id IN (:carIds)")
    fun loadAllByIds(carIds: IntArray): List<Car>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM car WHERE owner = :owner")
    fun loadAllByOwner(owner: Int): List<Car>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM car WHERE plate = :plate")
    fun loadByPlate(plate: String): Car

    @Insert
    abstract fun insert(car: Car)

    @Delete
    fun delete(car: Car)

    @Update
    fun update(car: Car)

}

@Dao
interface CustomerDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM customer")
    fun getAll(): List<Customer>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE id IN (:customerIds)")
    fun loadAllByIds(customerIds: IntArray): List<Customer>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM customer WHERE name = :name AND surname = :surname")
    fun loadByNameAndSurname(name: String, surname: String): Customer

    @Insert
    abstract fun insert(customer: Customer)

    @Delete
    fun delete(customer: Customer)

    @Update
    fun update(customer: Customer)

}

@Dao
interface InterventionDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM intervention")
    fun getAll(): List<Intervention>

    @Insert
    fun insert(intervention: Intervention)

    @Delete
    fun delete(intervention: Intervention)

    @Update
    fun update(intervention: Intervention)


}
```

My database:

```
@Database(entities = [Customer::class, Car::class, Intervention::class], version = 1)
abstract class Database : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun customerDao(): CustomerDao
    abstract fun carDao(): CarDao
    abstract fun interventionDao(): InterventionDao

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: Database? = null

        fun getDatabase(context: Context): Database {
            val tempInstance = INSTANCE
            if (tempInstance != null) {
                return tempInstance
            }
            synchronized(this) {
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    Database::class.java,
                    "database"
                ).build()
                INSTANCE = instance
                return instance
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the error:

```
file:///C:/Users/Megaport/AndroidStudioProjects/ProgettoOfficina2/app/src/main/java/com/example/progettoofficina2/CarManagerFragment.kt:39:23 Unresolved reference: getDatabase
file:///C:/Users/Megaport/AndroidStudioProjects/ProgettoOfficina2/app/src/main/java/com/example/progettoofficina2/CarManagerFragment.kt:40:21 Unresolved reference: carDao
```

It also seems to give me a problem with the adapters, but i'll ask for help for that on another post if the error persists after i solve this (as i am suspicious the two errors are tied to each other)

Comment: Can you paste the actual text of the error message, and can we see your entity and DAO classes?

Comment: Need to see your Database file, based on what those errors are.

Comment: I don't see a problem with that code, so you may be right that the adapter problem is causing this downstream issue. So can you show the text of that error message? By the way, you need to check for null again inside that `syncrhonized` block and return it if non-null. That's an oversight in the Room With a View tutorial. You can look up a double-checked locked singleton to understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would sugest a couple of changes:

1. **Do not name your class Database** as it is an annotation class of Room and may lead to some other errors.
2. Move to MVVM architecture as it may help you separate the concepts and point out the errors more accurately. And i do not have the lines to explain how this is done and the improvemnts you can achieve by doing this!

So point 2 to future reference! please read about that!

About your error - if point 1 does not solve it, try to **instantiate you database in the activity** and then pass what you need to the fragment and viceversa so you can save the 'new cars' in activity - probably save them in a list as the user creates new one and then pass the list to activity so it can save to database. All this is so much easier in mvvm.
Don't now if it helps but hope at least you give it a look at mvvm.

Comment: Oh, that's a good catch. The unresolved references might be because a different class name Database has been imported in this file.